# pytest - command line argument outside test function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

How to pass command line option as variable to my pytest non test file e.g. database name.

When i try:

```py
import sys
import getopt


"""argv = sys.argv[1:]

opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "e:")

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ['-e']:
        if arg == "test1":
            base_url = "url-test1.com"
            db_name = "db_test1"
        elif arg == 'test2':
            base_url = "url-test2.com"
            db_name = "db_test2"
        elif arg == 'test3':
            base_url = "url-test3.com"
            db_name = "db_test3"
    return base_url
```

and run

```
 python -m pytest -e test1
```

looks like pytest can't get -e flag

ERROR: usage: **main**.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]

**main**.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -e

inifile: None

I also try pytest addoption and passing variable to test files works fine but how to pass cmnd line option as value to non test file?

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default="url-test1.com")
    parser.addoption("--db", action="store", default="test1")

@pytest.fixture()
def url(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--url")

def db_name(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--db") #I want to pass this value to mysql.connector as database=db_name
```

**EDIT 1**

so my db_connect.py lokks like that

```
import mysql.connector
import argparse


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--db', required=True, type=str, help="Your database name")
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    db = args.db
    return db


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='username',
    password='password',
    host='host',
    database=main()
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and when i try to run

```
py.test --db test1
```

I got this error

```
ERROR: usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --db
  inifile: None
```

but when i run

```
py.test
```

i got

```
usage: py.test [-h] --db DB
py.test: error: the following arguments are required: --db
```

argument is required but when i pass it is unrecognized. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Specifically to "override" variables, modules and objects you should mock them. Mocking in testing refers to creating a fake object with similar behavior to the original one when creating the real object is expensive. Such as database connections. But, naturally, it isn't restricted to just databases. You can mock any object, as well as `sys.argv`.
You can read more extensively about mocking in the `pytest` [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) but here's a short example

```py
import module_to_test


def mytest(monkeypatch):
    """
    Mocks the configuration parameters values.
    """
    monkeypatch.setattr(module_to_test.sys, 'argv', ['somescript.py', '--db'])
```

That being said, I *strongly* recommend you do not use `getopt`. That is a deprecated method to parse arguments from the world of `bash`. There is a strong package called `argparse` that entirely replaces any such argument boilerplate code.

```py
import argpase


def parse_args():
    """
    Parse arguments given in the command line. Expects just "--db"
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--db', required=True, type=str, help="Your DB name")
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    db = args.db
    print(f"Wrap 10 to {db}. Engage!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

## edit 1

Great work on that `argparse`!

Now, you can simply mock it. You don't need it parsing the command line, anymore. You want to control what it returns. So, this time, when you use `monkeypatch` to mock `argparse.ArgumentParser`, you'll pass in your own "dummy class" that does nothing but return fixed arguments when `parser.parse_args()` is called. Here's an example of such a class (you'll probably want to tweak it)

```py
from collections import namedtuple


class DummyParser:
    def add_argument(self, *_, **__):
        """
        We know what arguments we want, we don't need to implement this.
        """
        pass

    def parse_args():
        """
        Money time!
        """
        fake_return_class = namedtuple('Namespace',
                                       ['db', 'the value we want for db'])
        args = fake_return_class(db="the value we want")
        return args


fake_parser = DummyParser()
fake_args = fake_parser.parse_args()
print(fake_args.db)
```

One tweak could be to make it a little more reusable and add your own constructor of what'll `db` be equal to.

Comment: as in EDIT 1 when i try to run it there is an Error:
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --db

Comment: @Pat77 Not sure if you get notifications of answer edits but adding a little more. Have fun!